# Update newly added field from previous record in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with share prices of different companies for each date. The fields are

```
 Date | Symbol | Closing_Rate.
```

Now I have added one more field to this table Previous Day Closing Rate.

```
Date | Symbol | Closing_Rate | Pre_Cls_Rate
```

Please help me for a query to update the previous date's closing rate to current date's field named "Pre_Cls_Rate"
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a redundancy

Answer (score 0):

As Strawberry said, It is a redundancy, you don't need to add new column to get data for another row from the same table, you can just change your query when you want to get data with something like :

```
select t1.*,t2.Closing_Rate as Pre_Cls_Ratefrom yourTable t1 inner JOIN yourTable t2 where t1.Symbol=t2.Symbol and t2.Date <= DATE(DATE_SUB(t1.Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`) and t2.Date > DATE(DATE_SUB(t1.Date, INTERVAL 2 DAY)`)
```